# Finding files with a wildcard and sorting by modified date in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, directory, getfiles

I have a folder that could contain a mix of files. I want to find files in the folder that match a pattern e.g.

```
"template*.txt"
```

and return the most recently modified one.

I can see that I could use Directory.Getfiles to get the list, as it supports wildcards, and then loop through the list checking for the modified date of each file, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to ask for things in this order from the filesystem, so any approach you take will ultimately be doing as you say (looping through the list and checking the modified date).  The loop might be explicit, or it might be implicit as in the Linq code in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Dim folder As New DirectoryInfo(folderPath)
Dim mostRecentlyModifiedFile = folder.EnumerateFiles(searchPattern).
                                      OrderByDescending(Function(fi) fi.LastWriteTime).
                                      FirstOrDefault()
```

That will give you a `FileInfo` object or `Nothing` if there is no matching file.

`EnumerateFiles` is preferred over `GetFiles` unless you specifically want all the files before processing them. You should read the documentation for each to see what the specific difference is.

Comment: Many thanks for this @jmcilhinney this works but I note that it's returning the oldest file rather than the newest. I'm to this and it's not obvious to me what I need to do to make it return the most recently modified file.

Comment: I worked it out in the end. I needed to swap OrderBy with OrderByDescending.  Thanks again.